# 401 Unauthorized Web service Error

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest-client

I have java spring framework web application running on JBoss clustered environment. In application user can generate few reports and will be able to view in UI itself. On click of generate report button we call SAP web service which returns result in response.SAP Web service Authentication is being done by hard coded  user id and password which will not change for any user.

The problem which we are facing now is out of 100 hits on generate report on an average 10 times its failing with error message "401 Unauthorized"

Comment: is there a throttling on number of requests for reports at a time?

Comment: we can have n number of hits at same time but by different users. same user can't hit again unless previous request is finished.